# MUI-Datatable: TableHead inside Expandable Row keeps on repeating for every row of the table and table does not center

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, mui-datatable

How do I solve this? Table headings just keep on repeating for every row in the table as seen in the picture below. Also, the table is always at the far end of the right side. How can I make this at the center as well?

[image]

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-fog-s984v0?file=/src/App.js

codes:

```
 const options = {
    filter: true,
    selectableRows: "none",
    responsive: "simple",
    expandableRows: true,
    renderExpandableRow: (rowData, rowMeta) => {
      console.log(rowData, "rowData");
      return Object.entries(rowData[3]).map(([key, value]) => {
        return (
          <TableContainer>
            <Table>
              <TableHead>
                <TableCell align="right">Name</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">Color</TableCell>
              </TableHead>
              <TableBody>
                <TableRow key={key}>
                  <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                    {value.name}
                  </TableCell>

                  <TableCell align="right">{value.color}</TableCell>

                  {/* Product: {value.name} + {value.size} +{" "}
                  {value.color + value.quantity} */}
                </TableRow>
              </TableBody>
            </Table>
          </TableContainer>
        );
      });
    }
  };
```

Comment: Is there some problem with my answer? As far as I can understand, that is what you wanted.

Comment: @Nemanja sorry, took too long for me to accept it because it was night time at that time. And thank you for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing your `options` object like below, shoud resolve issue.

```
const options = {
    filter: true,
    selectableRows: "none",
    responsive: "scrollMaxHeight",
    expandableRows: true,
    renderExpandableRow: (rowData, rowMeta) => {
      console.log(rowData);
      return (
        <tr>
          <td colSpan={4}>
            <TableContainer>
              <Table style={{ margin: "0 auto" }}>
                <TableHead>
                  <TableCell align="right">Name</TableCell>
                  <TableCell align="right">Color</TableCell>
                </TableHead>
                <TableBody>
                  {rowData[3].map((row) => {
                    console.log(row);
                    return (
                      <TableRow key={row.id}>
                        <TableCell component="th" scope="row" align="right">
                          {row.name}
                        </TableCell>
                        <TableCell align="right">{row.color}</TableCell>
                      </TableRow>
                    );
                  })}
                </TableBody>
              </Table>
            </TableContainer>
          </td>
        </tr>
      );
    }
  };
```